# Subclass issue (JAVA)

Tags: java

I have a class `Appointment` with fields:

- `int day`
- `int month`
- `int year`
- `String desc`

This stores the description of the appointment along with the date.

Super class `Appointment`:

```
public class Appointment {
    int dayNum;
    int monthNum;
    int yearNum;
    String desc;

    public Appointment(String des, int day) {
        //Monthly Appointments (Check day)
        desc = des;
        dayNum = day;
    }
    public Appointment(String des, int day, int month){
        //Yearly Appointments (Check day AND month)   
        desc = des;
        dayNum = day;
        monthNum = month;
    }
    public Appointment(String des, int day, int month, int year){
        //One Time (Check All)
        desc = des;
        dayNum = day;
        monthNum = month;
        yearNum = year;
    }     
}
```

Here are my 3 sub classes:

**A one time Appointment:** `Onetime`

```
public class OneTime extends Appointment{
    public OneTime(String des, int day, int month, int year){
        super(des, day, month, year);
    }
    public String getDesc(){
        return desc;
    }
}
```

**Once a month Appointments:** `Monthly`

```
public class Monthly extends Appointment{
    public Monthly(String des, int monum){
        super(des, monum);
    }
    public String getDesc(){
        return desc;
    }
}
```

**Once a year Appointments** `Yearly`

```
public class Yearly extends Appointment{
    public Yearly(String des, int day, int month){
        super(des, day, month);
    }
    public String getDesc(){
        return desc;
    }
}
```

**Problem:** I am asked to add a handful of various `Appointment` objects to an `ArrayList` (which I know). However, I must write a method `occursOn(int day, int month, int year)` that returns all appointments on that day. The part I am not sure about is writing the `occursOn()` method. Say I had an Appointment for 11/22/2018 , how would I compare a Monthly object to the day parameter / Yearly compared to the month and day parameters / `OneTime` compared to all parameters?

**Textbook question:**  "  Implement a superclass `Appointment` and subclasses `Onetime`, `Daily`, and `Monthly`. An appointment has a description (for example, "see the dentist") and a date. Write a method `occursOn(int year, int month, int day)` that checks whether the appointment occurs on that date. For example, for a monthly appointment, you must check whether the day of the month matches. Then fill an array of `Appointment` objects with a mixture of appointments. Have the user enter a date and print out all appointments that occur on that date. "

Note: This is not my homework. I just have a unit test on this in 2 hours and am stuck.

Comment: That is some weird indentation

Comment: I'm sorry. Paste issue. Should have fix before.

Comment: `Monthly` will probably want to know the day of month.

Comment: You should have limits for appointments as well. As long as they're active, OneTime should match  day month year, Yearly should match day month, and Monthly should only match day.  If you arrive at a point where you feel you're doing too much limit comparison ( verifying that a monthly/yearly appointment is active, you can create several OneTime appointments and include them in the parent class).

Comment: I am thinking of adding the method occursOn() to all subclasses then writing another occursOn() method in the Appointment class that consists of nested if statements. I just think that this way is not very robust.

Comment: I recommend moving the question above the code, when looking at the question list, the first x characters are shown, by placing the question at the top, people will see the start of your question, and that increases viewer, what results in a higher chance for a good answer

Comment: Thank for advice. Very stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OccursOn()

Should be an abstract method in the superclass (Appointment).
Each one of your sub class will have to implements it accordingly.

Onetime - check day, month, and year.

Monthly - check day only.

Yearly - check day and month.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you may want to declare `Appointment` abstract, so that sublcasses have to implement some methods :

```
 public abstract class Appointment {

        int dayNum;
        int monthNum;
        int yearNum;
        String desc;

        public Appointment(String des, int day){desc = des; dayNum = day;} //Monthly Appointments (Check day)
        public Appointment(String des, int day, int month){desc = des; dayNum = day; monthNum = month;} //Yearly Appointments (Check day AND month)   
        public Appointment(String des, int day, int month, int year){desc = des; dayNum = day; monthNum = month; yearNum = year;} //One Time (Check All)    

        abstract boolean occursOn(int day, int month, int year);

        abstract String getDesc();

        }
```

Then, the implementation of `occursOn` in your classes could be :

**Monthly**

```
    boolean occursOn(int day, int month, int year){

                return (this.day == day);
}
```

**Yearly**

```
    boolean occursOn(int day, int month, int year){

        return (this.day == day) && (this.month == month);
}
```

**OneTime**

```
    boolean occursOn(int day, int month, int year){

                return (this.day == day) && (this.month == month) && (this.year == year);
}
```

Finally, assuming that `appointments` is a `List` you populated with various instances of the subclasses, have a general method (maybe in your main class), which will return the list of all corresponding `Appointment` objects :

```
public List<Appointment> occursOn(int year, int month, int day){

List<Appointment> result = new ArrayList<Appointment>();

  for(Appointment appointment : appointments){

    if(appointment.occursOn(year, month, day))
      result.add(appointment);
  }

return result;

}
```

Comment: Only thing I would change is Daily = Yearly but this is the answer the OP wants. I just wrote a much short version of it without coding it for him.

Comment: @pompanoSlayer : thanks I corrected this. The "user enters a date" part and some work is still to implement by the OP . :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to go would be a map that uses a "date" key with optional values, e.g. like this:

```
class DateKey {
  int day; //always needed
  Integer month; //null in case of monthlies
  Integer year; //null in case of monthlies and yearlies

  //override equals() and hashCode()
}
```

Use the date key for a map:

```
//handling this would be easier with Google Guava's Multimap, if you may use it
Map<DateKey, List<Appointment>> appointments = ...;
```

Then you use a 3-step lookup:

```
List<Appointment> onetimes = appointments.get(new DateKey( day, month, year) );
List<Appointment> yearlies= appointments.get(new DateKey( day, month, null) );
List<Appointment> monthlies = appointments.get(new DateKey( day, null, null) );
```

And finally combine the 3 lists.

Finally, the `DateKey` could also be part of the `Appointment` class which would make the mapping even more consistent. I'd probably use a slightly different name then (think of one) since it's not only a map key anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method to your Appointment class that determines if the Appointment is on on a given date like this.

```
public class Appointment {

    int dayNum;
    int monthNum;
    int yearNum;
    String desc;

    public Appointment(String des, int day){desc = des; dayNum = day;} //Monthly Appointments (Check day)
    public Appointment(String des, int day, int month){desc = des; dayNum = day; monthNum = month;} //Yearly Appointments (Check day AND month)
    public Appointment(String des, int day, int month, int year){desc = des; dayNum = day; monthNum = month; yearNum = year;} //One Time (Check All)

    boolean occuresOn(int day, int month, int year){
        if( (this.dayNum == day) && (this.monthNum == month) && (this.yearNum == year))
            return true;

        return false;

    }
}
```

And override this functionality in sub classes.

```
public class Monthly extends Appointment{

    public Monthly(String des, int monum){
        super(des, monum);
    }
    public String getDesc(){
        return desc;
    }

    boolean occuresOn(int day, int month, int year){
        if( (this.dayNum == day) )
            return true;

        return false;

    }
}

public class Yearly extends Appointment{

    public Yearly(String des, int day, int month){
        super(des, day, month);
    }
    public String getDesc(){
        return desc;
    }

    boolean occuresOn(int day, int month, int year){
        if( (this.dayNum == day) && (this.monthNum == month))
            return true;

        return false;

    }
}
```

now you can iterate over your appointments and find those that are on a date:

```
List<Appointment> aps = new ArrayList<>(); //initialize this
    for (Appointment ap : aps){
        if(ap.occuresOn(2, 3, 2016))
            ....
    }
```